# Using learning rate schedule and learning rate warmup with TensorFlow2

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have to use learning rate warmup where you start training a VGG-19 CNN for CIFAR-10 with warmup from a learning rate of 0.00001 to 0.1 over the first 10000 iterations (or, approximately 13 epochs) using learning rate warmup. And then for the remainder of training, you use the learning rate of 0.01 where a learning rate decay is used to reduce the learning rate by a factor of 10 at 80 and 120 epochs. The model has to be trained for a total of 144 epochs.

I am using Python 3 and TensorFlow2 where training dataset has 50000 examples and batch size = 64. The number of training iterations in one epoch = 50000/64 = 781 iterations (approx.).
How can I use both of the learning rate warmup and learning rate decay together in the code?

Currently, I am using a learning rate decay by:

```
boundaries = [100000, 110000]
values = [1.0, 0.5, 0.1]

learning_rate_fn = keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(
    boundaries, values)
print("\nCurrent step value: {0}, LR: {1:.6f}\n".format(optimizer.iterations.numpy(), optimizer.learning_rate(optimizer.iterations)))
```

However, I don't know how to use a learning rate warmup along with learning rate decay.

Help?

Answer (score 10):

what about using the [implementation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/optimization_tf.html#WarmUp)  from the Transformers library?

```
from typing import Callable

import tensorflow as tf


class WarmUp(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):

def __init__(
    self,
    initial_learning_rate: float,
    decay_schedule_fn: Callable,
    warmup_steps: int,
    power: float = 1.0,
    name: str = None,
):
    super().__init__()
    self.initial_learning_rate = initial_learning_rate
    self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
    self.power = power
    self.decay_schedule_fn = decay_schedule_fn
    self.name = name

def __call__(self, step):
    with tf.name_scope(self.name or "WarmUp") as name:
        # Implements polynomial warmup. i.e., if global_step < warmup_steps, the
        # learning rate will be `global_step/num_warmup_steps * init_lr`.
        global_step_float = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
        warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(self.warmup_steps, tf.float32)
        warmup_percent_done = global_step_float / warmup_steps_float
        warmup_learning_rate = self.initial_learning_rate * tf.math.pow(warmup_percent_done, self.power)
        return tf.cond(
            global_step_float < warmup_steps_float,
            lambda: warmup_learning_rate,
            lambda: self.decay_schedule_fn(step - self.warmup_steps),
            name=name,
        )

def get_config(self):
    return {
        "initial_learning_rate": self.initial_learning_rate,
        "decay_schedule_fn": self.decay_schedule_fn,
        "warmup_steps": self.warmup_steps,
        "power": self.power,
        "name": self.name,
    }
```

Comment: This is the should be marked as the answer. Any reason not to @Arun?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the learning rate scheduler to any optimizer by setting it to the `lr`  parameter. For example -

```
from tensorlow.keras.optimizers import schedules, RMSProp
boundaries = [100000, 110000]
values = [1.0, 0.5, 0.1]

lr_schedule = schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(boundaries, values)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

Comment: This is a linear learning rate decay which I am already using. I also want a linear learning rate warmup from step 0 to step 10000 where the learning rate is linearly increased from 0 to 0.1

Comment: did not worked for me. ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'PiecewiseConstantDecay' and 'int'``` at the end of the very first epoch.

Answer (score 0):

```
start = 0
warmup = 5000
multiplier = 10.0
boundaries = [start, warmup, 100000, 110000]
values = [0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01]

learning_rate_fn = keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(
    boundaries, values) * multiplier
print("\nCurrent step value: {0}, LR: {1:.6f}\n".format(optimizer.iterations.numpy(), optimizer.learning_rate(optimizer.iterations)))
```