# How to reset optimizer state from loaded checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I saved a model using the `ModelCheckpoint` callback using the `save_weights_only` option

```py
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            'path.ckpt, save_weights_only=True)
```

Then when I wanted to fine-tune on a smaller dataset I loaded it back up:

```py
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(model)
ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).expect_partial()
```

And I recompiled the model with a new optimizer:

```py
class CFG:
    _scheduler = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=lr, decay_rate=decay_rate)
    scheduler = WarmUp(
        initial_learning_rate=lr, decay_schedule_fn=_scheduler,
        warmup_steps=warmup_steps)
    optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
        weight_decay=1e-4, learning_rate=scheduler, epsilon=1e-8)

model.compile(
    optimizer=CFG.optimizer,
)
```

But the optimizer is somehow still stuck on the decayed lr from before rather than being set at the much higher lr I want now, and I'm not sure about the other optimizer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because you are using class attributes instead of instance attributes.

Fix:

```
class CFG:
  def __init__(self,lr,decay_rate,warmup_steps):
    _scheduler = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=lr, decay_rate=decay_rate)
    scheduler = WarmUp(
        initial_learning_rate=lr, decay_schedule_fn=_scheduler,
        warmup_steps=warmup_steps)
    self.optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
        weight_decay=1e-4, learning_rate=scheduler, epsilon=1e-8)

new_CFG=CFG(lr,decay_rate,warmup_steps)
model.compile(
    optimizer=new_CFG.optimizer,
)
```

Comment: Nice try, but unfortunately no cigar

Comment: I ended up just dropping the scheduler and the issue was gone. (not trivial because the scheduler is still involved in the pre-training - so I don't know how/why this satisfies it)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your bug unless the `model.compile` line is before `ckpt.restore`. That means you have to make sure that `model.compile` is after `ckpt.restore` and also a new optimizer is initialized as what I have done in the answer. You can also provide the codes for `WarmUp`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have those things in that order. `Warmup` looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65198840/4391249

Comment: To be honest though, my dirty fix is good enough for now.